# Joining columns in sql (php) don't show all results

Tags: php, sql, join, mysqli

The language is PHP and I have the following SQL syntax:

```
SELECT computers.user_1, computers.user_2, users.user_id as userId1, users.user_id as userId2
FROM computers
LEFT JOIN users ON computers.user_1 = users.id
LEFT JOIN users ON computers.user_2 = users.id
WHERE computers.id = '".$id."'
```

The table "computers" has columns "user_1", "user_2" and "user_3" which contains numbers that corresponds to the row id's of table "users". In "users" there is a column "user_id" (that looks something like ABC123).
This means that one user can be assigned to multiple computers.

This syntax doesn't work. Nothing shows up when I echo it. I can only echo one at a time. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set an alias for the table `users`

```
SELECT computers.user_1, computers.user_2, u1.user_id as userId1, u2.user_id as userId2
FROM computers
LEFT JOIN users as u1 ON computers.user_1 = u1.id
LEFT JOIN users as u2 ON computers.user_2 = u2.id
WHERE computers.id = '".$id."'
```